# How to check last release of php using php

Tags: php

Let's say I have some project on php. One of its functions should be to check whether the latest version of php is used on the server. For example, for security reasons. There are no problems to use [phpversion()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.phpversion.php) and [version_compare()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.version-compare.php).

But how can I programmatically get the latest stable version of php? Maybe there is some kind of API or something like that?

General conditions:

1. you need to get the latest release number of php using php itself;
2. HTML parsing is not suitable;
3. CLI or not — doesn't matter;
4. it would be cool (but not necessary) to check the latest release within one major branch.

I am curious whether you had such a task and how you solved it.

*This question is only about the software implementation of checking for updates, but not the update process itself.*

Comment: What should happen when there is a new PHP version that has not (yet) bee applied to the server? What if that new PHP version exists only for some operating systems/distros and not (yet) for the OS/distro being used by the server in question?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Ofcourse these nuances are important, but an opportunity to check for new versions of php by php-script is more interesting itself. The topic is about official releases and not about custom or "not popular" builds. So let's leave this questions to hypothetical server owner. He can get latest official php build for his server in different ways

Comment: I wan't thinking of custom/"not popular" builds, but of the fact that even the major Linux distributions will not have the new PHP version available at the same time it is published by the PHP maintainers. And some distribution might not even take it over if the new PHP version appears to have adverse effects or if the distribution only gets security updates.

Comment: And this completely ignores that company policy may dictate that a live server may not be updated until the new version has been validated in a test environment to ensure it won't break critical processes.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Try to abstract from all this. The question is only about the software implementation of checking for updates, and not the update itself. Server update is the task for server administrator. He can build php from source. Moreover, companies must have people responsible for such tasks. But it's not about that.

Comment: It is partially in scope, because it can affect what you use as source of information for the latest PHP release. That could be the github repository as explained in the answer by @ArseniMourzenko, but you could also decide to use the distribution's package manager as source for what is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP source is [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src/releases), and GitHub has an API. Therefore, you can:

1. Access the API in order to get the list of last revisions,
2. Filter the ones you don't want (for instance the ones containing “alpha” or “RC” in the names).
3. Parse the remaining revisions and sort the list (if you don't sort it, you'll get the revisions in the order when they were published; for example, at the moment of writing, php-7.2.19 appears *more* recent than php-7.3.6).
4. Get the last one in the list.
5. Compare.

Comment: Yep, sounds good. Moreover I can skip steps 2 and 3 and just receive the latest release using [this Github API method](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release)